# submit, keyup.enter not working on angular 10

Tags: angular

I am learning angular from basic in my code I want to send text from text box on `enter` to function when I tried with just `keyup` `keydown` it was working fine but when try to use `submit` `keyup.enter` the whole component disappear

diagnos.component.html:

```
<input type="text" #nameText (keyup.enter)="addItem(nameText.value)">
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let name of names">{{name}}</li>
</ul>
```

diagnos.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-diagnos',
  templateUrl: './diagnos.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./diagnos.component.css']
})
export class DiagnosComponent implements OnInit {
  names = ['abc','xyz'];
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    
  }
  addItem(val){
    this.names.push(val);
  }

}
```

idle page:
[image]

when used `keyup` only:
[image]

when used `keyup.enter` or `submit` after pressing `enter` or submitting:
[image]

after enter or submit whole component disappeared even that `ul` also and had tried logging on console if that function get call or not but that function doesn't call

my project link : https://github.com/ladbhupesh/angularapp

Comment: make a stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: where is your submit form action

Comment: @cagcak i want to use keyup.enter and submit event in textbox the neither of them works `addItem()` function doesn't call but if i use keyup only instead on keyup.enter or sumit `addItem()` functions get called

Comment: I still didn't understand the functionality here. your additem() works for enter keyup and it just appends items to array. but where is your submit action? can you show the issue on @KShewengger's stackblitz

Comment: yeah I saw it I shared my git repo of project I am implementing this in child component of app it is working on app.component but not in its child component diagnos.component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried to repro your code and all seems well especially `keyup.enter`

Attached herewith is the [Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-keyup-ente?file=src/app/app.component.html) for your reference.

May I know if what's missing?

---

**Update**

Based on the provided Github link you mentioned, when looking at the running code, seems like the `@Output EventEmitter` affects your `(keyup.enter)` which I'm quite not sure what went through your project as I have only scanned fragments of your code but you can resolve that issue by supplying this code below:

**AppComponent**

```
...
changePage(val) {
  if (typeof val === 'string') this.pageName = val;
}
```

What happened was, the event from `DiagnosisComponent's keyup.enter` was consoled or communicated on your `AppComponent's changePage` which it receives an object not string, resulting for the `pageName` to reinitialized it's value to the given object, thus, no components are being rendered and left your page empty as there are no `pageName` available for the given object.

You can check it out by performing `console.log(val)` inside your `AppComponent's changePage(val) {...} function`

Comment: I have added project github link please check i missed anything

Comment: thank you for your help its worked but can you explain me why `EventEmitter` interact with `keyup.enter` they are in different components they shouldn't interact with each other na?

Comment: Hi @Bhupeshlad, no problem, apologies, but this kind of error is quite new to me as well and yes, they shouldn't interact with each other so the behavior is quite weird in the first place. The folder structure or architecture may play a role in this issue to persist as well, if not, it may be best to debug around the code and see if what causes the issue

Answer (score 0):

This is how you trigger function with the enter key ,

```
 <input type="text" (keyup.enter)="function()">
```

not

```
(keyup.enter.p)
```

Comment: That was typo I fixed it but it isn't solves any problem

Answer (score -1):

(keyup.enter) worked for me when added it in container div not in input

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).